# Core Data NSFetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType not working

Tags: ios, core-data

When setting a NSFetchRequest result type to NSDictinaryResultType, zero objects are returned.  If I remove setPropertiesToFetch and setResultType, all the objects are returned.

Any ideas?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Alert" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSDictionary *entityProperties = [entity propertiesByName]; 
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[entityProperties objectForKey:@"test"]]];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (result == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was I needed to save the mangedObjectContext after inserting new objects.  Once I did that I get the results I was looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is a real gotcha. When using NSDictionaryResultsType you cannot get the results of pending changes on the managed object context.