# Core-data distinct fetch give empty array

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios6, nsfetchrequest

I've spent a few hours trying to get a fetch to work. I need to get rid of duplicates so I thought I could follow this guide [core-data-how-to-do-a-select-distinct](http://felipecypriano.com/2011/09/21/core-data-how-to-do-a-select-distinct/)
But It always give me an empty array.

Here's my code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RBTag" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]];
request.entity = entity;
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[entity propertiesByName] objectForKey:@"name"]];
request.returnsDistinctResults = YES;
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];


NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *distincResults = [[self context] executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];


NSLog(@"Result: %@", distincResults);
```

I get no error. I checked NSPropertyDescription and it do find my property. 
If I comment out:

```
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Then I get results but it's not distinct. =(

Comment: What happens if you comment out `returnsDistinctResults` but still have the result type set to `NSDictionaryResultType`? Does it return anything then?

Comment: No, still give me an empty array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing in any guides or in apple docs, but after hard googling I found this post: 
[bbarnheart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7020057/1356577)
Must save context to persistent store before changing the resultType to NSDictionaryResultType.

Comment: It is in the Apple docs, but hidden in the documentation of the `setIncludesPendingChanges:` property: "A value of YES is not supported in conjunction with the result type NSDictionaryResultType, including calculation of aggregate results (such as max and min). For dictionaries, the array returned from the fetch reflects the current state in the persistent store, and does not take into account any pending changes, insertions, or deletions in the context."

Answer (score 1):

`propertiesToFetch` expects an array of *property names*, but you set it to an array of `NSAttributeDescription`. Try

```
request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name"];
```

If you don't set `request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;` then `propertiesToFetch` is ignored.

Comment: request.propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name"]; was mutch less code. thanx!

Comment: It was also something completely different... ;-)