# executeFetchRequest is not working with propertiesToFetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

I have integrated coreData in my application. I am running `NSManagedObjectContext` in the main thread.

```
-(NSArray *) getResultForContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *allObjects = [self executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];

    return allObjects;
}
```

The above method is working fine but if I add `propertiesToFetch` to the request, `executeFetchRequest` return an empty array.

```
-(NSArray *) getResultForContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"firstName",@"lastName"]];
    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *allObjects = [self executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];

    return allObjects;
}
```

This method returns an empty.

What is missing here?

Comment: Show me the calls to this methods, where is your MOC allocated? If you are in multithreaded enviroment you should know that MOC is not threadsafe, so if you are calling this methods from threads other than the ones in which your MOC is created than you can expect some strange behaviour like the one you are having...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that (1) data is present (i.e. that there actually are some `Person` instances to be fetched) and that (2) the result is actually an empty array and not `nil`:

The only way I know to get a non-empty array in the first case but an empty array in the second case would be if the listed properties are both `nil` for *all* instances. In that case, there are no values, so the call to `setReturnsDistinctResult` effectively filters out every result (because `nil` is not considered a distinct result).

If either property is non-`nil` for any existing `Person` instance, you'll get a non-empty array. But if there are no property values to fetch, there are no distinct results, and the result is empty.

If it happens that the result is actually `nil`, and not an empty array, look at `fetchError` for clues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the NSDictionaryResultType.
As said bbarnhart on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019422/core-data-nsfetchrequest-setresulttypensdictionaryresulttype-not-working/7020057#7020057), you must save the context to persistent store before using the resultType NSDictionaryResultType.

Be careful to the declaration of the context persistentStoreCoordinator too.